# MongoDB Scema Design - Querying user information and monthly statistics

Tags: mongodb

In our mongodb database, we have a collection of users. Each user document contains some basic information about the user such as location, date of birth and sex. It contains a few additional properties, but that's the type of data we're storing.

We collect monthly statistics for each user as well. There are many different stats we're collection for a user, but the general idea is that for every month, there will be one document for each user. That document will contain many different attributes containing mostly numeric data. Here's an example monthly document.

```
{
  "UserId": ObjectId(""),
  "SummaryDate": ISODate("2014-09-01T04:00:00Z"),
  TotalViews: 34,
  Points: 300,
  Growth: 20.3
}
```

The business would like to query users based on stats. I've used mongodb in the past, but not for this use. My first thought was to merge additional properties into the monthly stats collection, but wanted to know what other people thought.

Some example reports

- Give me all users in Michigan where their growth (stat in monthly summary) between start month and end month is greater than X.
- Give me all users in Michigan and show me their stats for months June, July and August inline and we want to be able to sort by a specific month's stats. Table would look like this: 
  `[ Full Name | Location | June 2014 Views | June 2014 Growth | July 2015 | July 2015 Growth ]`

Appreciate your thoughts.

EDIT: I also have to support some form of pagination and sorting on all fields.

Comment: to do the sort of dimensional querying you would need to either keep these attributes in the summary documents (if there are not too many of them, remember they should be indexed which will slow down your writes somewhat) *or* you could possibly query for user id's for appropriate attribute and then query the summary collection for only user Ids you want, but that's unlikely to scale if you have millions of users from Michigan, for example.  I would suggest going with keeping attributes in summary document.

Comment: Thanks. The only issue that I see with that is pagination and sorting. It's easy if they're sorting off of the user filtered data, but if they're sorting on a stat column, it would be sorted by users included in the first user batch.

Comment: Seems like a candidate for [MongoDB's Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/).

Comment: Right, but how should I design the documents for the pipeline? I've used the pipeline in the past, but I want to make sure I have the documents correct before I start that process. I get how to use it for the stat calculation. I'm just looking for feedback on the querying based on user data and stat data.

Comment: I don't understand your concern about sorting - you can filter one one field and then sort on another field without any issues (you need to have the right index or else the sort would be in memory) but that's not an obstacle to find queries or aggregations.

Comment: The issue was related to the first option - grabbing IDs from the primary user collection and then using them to grab stats from the stats collection. If I'm sorting by some value in the stats collection, that option wouldn't work.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend grabbing id's from user collection even though it would work to sort by stats (it wouldn't work to sort by something from the user collection though).  See my answer for option to keep attributes in the summary document.  That seems to make more sense given your description of the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the sort of dimensional querying you would need to keep these attributes in the summary documents (assuming there are not too many of them, since they should be indexed which will slow down your writes somewhat).

So assuming a document:

```
{
  "UserId": ObjectId(""),
  "FullName":"Joe Shmoe",
  "Location":"Michigan",
  "SummaryDate": ISODate("2014-09-01T04:00:00Z"),
  TotalViews: 34,
  Points: 300,
  Growth: 20.3
}
```

To do the second query based on state would be something like this:

All users in Michigan (optionally other attribute filters), and show me their stats for months June, July and August sorting by July's stats.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    {"$match":{
        "Location":"Michigan", 
        "SummaryDate":{"$gt":ISODate("2014-06-01T04:00:00Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2014-09-01T04:00:00Z")}
    } },
    {"$group": {
         "_id":"$UserId",
         "Full Name":{$first:"$FullName"},
         "Location":{$first:"$Location"},
         "June views": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},6]},then:"$TotalViews",else:0}}},
         "June growth": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},6]},then:"$Growth",else:0}}},
         "July views": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},7]},then:"$TotalViews",else:0}}},
         "July growth": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},7]},then:"$Growth",else:0}}},
         "Aug views": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},8]},then:"$TotalViews",else:0}}},
         "Aug growth": {$sum:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$month:"$SummaryDate"},8]},then:"$Growth",else:0}}},
    } },
    {"$sort":{"July views":1} }
]);
```

Output will be list of documents something like this sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543445dd19b404b29e503f94"),
    "Full Name" : "Jane Shmoe",
    "Location" : "Michigan",
    "June views" : 0,
    "June growth" : 0,
    "July views" : 40,
    "July growth" : 20.3,
    "Aug views" : 340,
    "Aug growth" : 20.3
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback on this. Great, useful example too. Appreciate it.